# Can you call a function as part of an SQL statement at the .execute line?

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access, ms-access-2010

I have been tasked with doing some upgrades to a "data converter" that our companie uses to standardize client data. The "data converter" is from at least 2006, but could be much older. I have a fairly good understanding of VBA and some knowledge of SQL.

The actual conversion of data takes place in one very very long SQL statement (2,600 characters). It is built from many strings like the below. I am having trouble understanding the BreakName part, and was hoping someone could shed some light on it.

```
strSQLCompleteName = "BreakName(Trim([" & CStr(cboDBFieldFirstName) & "]),""" & txtNameDelimiter & """,3,1) AS UL_COMPLETE_NAME"
```

The BreakName part is a function in another module, but I wouldn't have thought you could call a function as part of a .Execute statement.

Comment: That is exactly my question. I wouldn't think that it could. But somehow that line is be executed.

Comment: Where's the code that actually runs this?

Comment: Everything is written in Access

Comment: I am going to assume from your first comment, that I am right in thinking you can't call a function as part of a .Execute statement. I'll spend some more time and hopefully figure out the purpose of these line.

Comment: It appears the BreakName function is something akin to the split function. But to your question you are populating the variable strSQLCompleteName using a function call which is fine. I am assuming somewhere later all the string get concatenated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer my own question, you can call a sub/function from within an SQL statement. I got it working again, and then went line by line at the .execute line to see what happened.